# Wi-Fi menu does not appear on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: wireless, 20.04

The Wi-Fi menu itself doesn't appear after installing Ubuntu 20.04 in my computer.

[image: image 1]

[image: image 2]

[image: image 3]

Comment: @David I think this user was trying to demonstrate that there is no wifi showing on the second picture. I guess we would have to know Korean or something to make sense of the first picture.  I would suggest the user should check to see if there are hardware switches to turn on ?.?

Comment: @David PonJar's comment is right. I just wanted to  show the status bar in the upper right corner. However, I didn't know how to cut and upload the picture, so I posted the picture as it was. The site in the picture is just a Korean site for Ubuntu. But I apologize if it looked like an advertisement.